# aspas simples não esta funcionando dentro de formulário

Tags: php, javascript, html

Meu código não está aceitando ser escrito com aspas simples, para poder fica dentro do `echo`.

Como fazer para resolver essa situação?

A linha com erro: `$("input[name='enable']")`

```
echo
    " ...
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        ...
        $("input[name='enable']").click(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('input.textbox:text').attr('disabled', false);
            } else if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
                var remove = '';
                $('input.textbox:text').attr ('value', remove);
                $('input.textbox:text').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
        ...
    </script>
    ...";
```

Comment: Para deixar claro, o problema é escapar as aspas duplas dentro da string no PHP. Como citado na pergunta que citei, basta fazer `$(\"input[name='enable']\")`, assim a string não será finalizada no PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Você começa com:

```
echo
    "
```

E no meio do código tem isto:

```
"input[name='enable']"
```

Ou seja a aspas do `"input[name='enable']"` estão "quebrando" as aspas do `echo "...";`, você deveria "escapar" as aspas assim:

```
echo
    " ...
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        ...
        $(\"input[name='enable']\").click(function(){
```

Fora que o `$` do jQuery ou outras variaveis dentro de "aspas normais" pode se confundir com variaveis PHP

**No entanto** escapar várias aspas é algo que demora muito, então recomendo duas maneiras mais simples, se tiver mais HTML no script que PHP de fato seria interessante isolar o PHP e o HTML usando a [sintaxe alternativa do PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), assim por exemplo:

```php
<?php if (codição): ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        ...
        $("input[name='enable']").click(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('input.textbox:text').attr('disabled', false);
            } else if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
                var remove = '';
                $('input.textbox:text').attr ('value', remove);
                $('input.textbox:text').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
        ...
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Outra maneira é usar o [`Heredoc`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```php
echo <<<EOF
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        ...
        $("input[name='enable']").click(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('input.textbox:text').attr('disabled', false);
            } else if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
                var remove = '';
                $('input.textbox:text').attr ('value', remove);
                $('input.textbox:text').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
        ...
    </script>
EOF;
```

Documentação:

- [Alternative Sintaxe](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)
- [Heredoc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)